# Why does "pip install google.cloud" not enable bigquery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

We are trying to get the following command to work from [this python example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery_load_table_gcs_csv-python) for loading a CSV file into BigQuery from Google Cloud Storage:

```
 from google.cloud import bigquery
```

But after doing `pip install google.cloud` we receive the following error when we try to run that command:

> ImportError: cannot import name bigquery

If we installed `google.cloud` - shouldn't `bigquery` be included? What are missing?

We are running Python 2.7.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like [installing `google-cloud` may once have behaved as you expect, but no longer does](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/):

> WARNING: The google-cloud Python package is deprecated. On June 18, 2018, this package will no longer install any other packages. Please install the [product-specific google-cloud-* packages](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-python-client) needed for your application.

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) now says that the Python BigQuery client library is called `google-cloud-bigquery`. Try installing that instead.