# ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery'

Tags: python, google-bigquery

This must be a super trivial issue, but i've updated my windows virtual machine with;

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

However, when I run the script I still receive the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.cloud import bigquery, storage
ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery'
```

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Thanks,
Neel R

Comment: Is your pip version the same as your python version? ie. have you tried `pip3 install ...`?

Comment: I did yes, turns out that I needed to install the client-specific library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a fresh setup of the VM;

Failed - `pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud`

Worked - `pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`

Worked - `pip3 install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`

It appears that individual product solutions should be installed instead of the generic google-cloud.

If you're still stuck, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017778/why-does-pip-install-google-cloud-not-enable-bigquery) helped!

Answer (score 36):

I was facing the same problem.But applying every answer nothing was working.
Then I noticed that pip need to be ungraded. So I upgrade pip first.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then I try this solution just changing a little bit https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895009/5393858

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

Comment: This worked for me! Previously google-cloud-bigquery was stuck on... "3.5"->google-resumable-media<2.0dev,>=0.6.0->google-cloud-bigquery) (2.20)
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio..... updating pip first on the instance worked. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try loading pip as a python module to ensure you're using the pip instance that your python executable is linked to.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

Comment: Turns out that I needed to the specific client :( Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need to upgrade anything. The resolution was installing both `google-cloud` and `google-cloud-bigquery` pip dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In my instance some older versions of the google cloud being installed caused the problem. So, uninstalled all google libraries through pip (did sudo pip uninstall as well, since some libraries were installed at that user level), and also removed manually any google libraries from